# The area within the icon is not clickable for my clickable dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, icons

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu that displays the dropdown content when it is clicked.

I noticed that when the button contains a text, it behaves what I want it to be. However, when it contains an icon from fontawesome.com, when I click the area within the icon, the dropdown menu does not showup. Strangely, when I click on the area within the button that is not covered by the icon, the dropdown shows up.

I tried to change the icon using ones from material.io, and the issue is still there.

I'm not sure which part of my code is causing the problem. Thanks in advance.

here is my code:

html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
            <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

            <a href="#">
                Link 1
                <div></div>
            </a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
        /* Dropdown Button */
        .dropbtn {
            /*sample code for center align text*/
            background-color: #97d5ff;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            font-size: 1.3em;
            border: 0px solid white;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 2.1em;
            height: 2.1em;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;

        }

        /* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
        .dropbtn:hover,
        .dropbtn:focus {
            background-color: #2980B9;
            outline-width: 0px;
        }

        /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
        .dropdown {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            z-index: 1;
        }

        /* Links inside the dropdown */
        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd
        }

        /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
        .show {
            display: block;
        }
```

javascript

```
        /* When the user clicks on the button,
        toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }

        // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The event function is linked to dropdown HTMLElement, when you click the icon, the event is sent by the Font Awesome Icon instead, the simplest way to solve is by using *the pointer-events: none;* property in it to disable it's capacity to do so.

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
      <i class="far fa-envelope" style="pointer-events: none;"></i>
 </button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately this does not work on my code =(

Comment: Tested this with Heroicons placed inside Mantine inputs and it works well

Answer (score 1):

So after reading this page:
https://material.io/develop/web/components/buttons/icon-buttons

I realized that the correct way of using these icons are adding the class "material-icons" to the button, rather than wrapping an element with a the class "material-icons" within the button.

Therefore,

```
<button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons">favorite</button>
```

fixes the issue.

However, I'm still wondering why this modification fixes the issue.
Any explanation would be great! Thanks!